# Second HDD idles periodically

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I just purchased an SSD and clean installed windows 10 in it, now my old HDD (non-SSD, SAMSUNG HD103SJ) keeps idling periodically. I still have most of my data in it since the SSD is small and only used for system and smaller apps, so whenever I'm playing music or using things off the old HDD i keep hearing ticks as the HDD spins back up from idle after reading data.

What I have tried is write a random text file to the HDD every 5 seconds via script. It works, but I'm worried this will needlessly wear down the HDD.

Is there any other way I can prevent this from happening without risk of reducing it's durability?

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel, Power Options, Change Plan Settings, Change Advanced Power settings, then where it says "Turn Hard Disks after" instead of selecting a number of minutes, set it to say "never" ... should have helped.

Comment: That is not the issue/solution. Even when set to never, it still idles every 8 or 10 seconds or so. It's not fully shutting down, it's just parking the head (which makes the "tick" noise)

Comment: I guess it depends of mainboard... for example... I got Asus P5K Premium, 2xSSD in raid + 6xHDD in raid... when I had that option on, it took like a minute to access my HDD matrix (every harddrive had to start spinning etc etc)... but when I set that to "never", didn't notice any significant delays.

Comment: It doesn't really take a minute to access or anything (maybe a second or two) My biggest issue is that the "click" is particularly loud for this HDD

Comment: oh in my case it took really long before... maybe because of RAID.